# Inserting newly created ID into two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

Below the script does not work but only working if it inserting a single row.

The documentId should not be declared on first line but from the retrieve from `DOCUMENTS` table.

I read about `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` but not sure how to apply it.

`[dbo].[DOCUMENTS].DOCUMENT_ID` is a primary key with auto increment int.

What is required is for every row inserted into `DOCUMENTS` table, it automatically insert and add it to the last row and use the newly created `DOCUMENT_ID` to populate `@documentId` defined in two table below.

```
declare @documentId int;
set @documentId = (SELECT MAX(DOCUMENT_ID) FROM dbo.DOCUMENTS)+ 1

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DOCUMENTS] (
       DOCUMENT_ID
      ,DOCUMENT_TYPE
      ,DOCUMENT_REF
      ,DOCUMENT_NOTE
      ,DOCUMENT_DATE
      ,LAST_UPDATE_ID
      ,LAST_UPDATE_DATE
      ,DOCUMENT_FUNCTION_CODE
      ,BATCH_ID
      ,AUDIT_XML
      ,AUDIT_USER
      ,REMINDER_DATE)
     SELECT
     @documentId,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     'MIGRATED FROM BRING UP NOTES ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + sr.BRINGUP_NOTES,
     GETDATE(),
     NULL,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     sr.BRINGUP_DATE
     FROM [dbo].[SERVICE_REQUESTS] sr

----- Insert into another table ------------
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SERVICE_REQUEST_ITEM_DOCS] (
  [SERVICE_REQUEST_ID]
      ,[SERVICE_REQUEST_ITEM_SEQNO]
      ,[DOCUMENT_ID]
      ,[LAST_UPDATE_ID]
      ,[LAST_UPDATE_DATE]
      ,[COVER_LETTER])
     SELECT 
     sr.SERVICE_REQUEST_ID,
     1,
     @documentId,
     0,
     GETDATE(),
     0
     FROM [dbo].[SERVICE_REQUESTS] sr
```

Comment: Why are you passing value for Primary key column with auto increment?

Comment: Sorry. SQL is not my strongest. How should it be done?

Comment: @PareshJ I am trying to generate a new Id and reuse it when inserting into both tables

Answer (score 1):

As you have Doucment_ID as primary key with auto increment value, you dont have to pass variable in your 1st Insert statement. I have made some correction in your insert statements, check out my answer.

```
declare @documentId int;


INSERT INTO [dbo].[DOCUMENTS] (
      DOCUMENT_TYPE
      ,DOCUMENT_REF
      ,DOCUMENT_NOTE
      ,DOCUMENT_DATE
      ,LAST_UPDATE_ID
      ,LAST_UPDATE_DATE
      ,DOCUMENT_FUNCTION_CODE
      ,BATCH_ID
      ,AUDIT_XML
      ,AUDIT_USER
      ,REMINDER_DATE)
     SELECT
     NULL,
     NULL,
     'MIGRATED FROM BRING UP NOTES ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + sr.BRINGUP_NOTES,
     GETDATE(),
     NULL,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     sr.BRINGUP_DATE
     FROM [dbo].[SERVICE_REQUESTS] sr

Set @documentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

----- Insert into another table ------------
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SERVICE_REQUEST_ITEM_DOCS] (
  [SERVICE_REQUEST_ID]
      ,[SERVICE_REQUEST_ITEM_SEQNO]
      ,[DOCUMENT_ID]
      ,[LAST_UPDATE_ID]
      ,[LAST_UPDATE_DATE]
      ,[COVER_LETTER])
     SELECT 
     sr.SERVICE_REQUEST_ID,
     1,
     @documentId,
     0,
     GETDATE(),
     0
     FROM [dbo].[SERVICE_REQUESTS] sr
```

Comment: you sure this work? I dont have access to the database now.

Comment: I don't think this is how you use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: It will work, if you are not sure check out on GOOGLE.. for syntax. It will be the same as I used.

Comment: How does SCOPE_IDENTITY() point the newly created DOCUMENT_ID?

Comment: Check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() will have last inserted identity value in the database. 
You can use Ident_Current(table name) to get the last identity value inserted int he desired table.                                                                      
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql

Comment: I not sure if this would work since i need the documentid from the first insert and populate straight to the next table insert. I need the newly created last documentid and not the final final documentid to populate the next table insert.

Comment: @PareshJ will SCOPE_IDENTITY() return me a list of documendIds for my next database insert? That's what I am expecting.

Comment: @PareshJ My first insection into table will be inserting hundreds of records so i am expecting a list of different documentids returned

Comment: Just found out the document_id is not auto increament. This is causing issue.

Comment: @PareshJ My table column is not increment id so this does not work

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cant insert auto increment column without setting its identity on

```
    declare @documentId int;
    --set @documentId = (SELECT MAX(DOCUMENT_ID) FROM dbo.DOCUMENTS)+ 1

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DOCUMENTS] (DOCUMENT_TYPE      ,DOCUMENT_REF      ,DOCUMENT_NOTE      ,DOCUMENT_DATE      ,LAST_UPDATE_ID      ,LAST_UPDATE_DATE      ,DOCUMENT_FUNCTION_CODE      ,BATCH_ID      ,AUDIT_XML      ,AUDIT_USER      ,REMINDER_DATE)
         SELECT     NULL,     NULL,     'MIGRATED FROM BRING UP NOTES ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + sr.BRINGUP_NOTES,     GETDATE(),     NULL,     NULL,     NULL,     NULL,     NULL,     NULL,     sr.BRINGUP_DATE
         FROM [dbo].[SERVICE_REQUESTS] sr

    set @documentid=@@identity() 

--or      set @documentid=SCOPE_Identity()  


    ----- Insert into another table ------------
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[SERVICE_REQUEST_ITEM_DOCS] (
      [SERVICE_REQUEST_ID]
          ,[SERVICE_REQUEST_ITEM_SEQNO]
          ,[DOCUMENT_ID]
          ,[LAST_UPDATE_ID]
          ,[LAST_UPDATE_DATE]
          ,[COVER_LETTER])
         SELECT 
         sr.SERVICE_REQUEST_ID,
         1,
         @documentId,
         0,
         GETDATE(),
         0
         FROM [dbo].[SERVICE_REQUESTS] sr
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that DOCUMENT_ID is an identity column you can use an output clause to get the new ID, for example:

```
DECLARE @DOCUMENT_ID int
DECLARE @TID TABLE (DOCUMENT_ID int)

INSERT INTO SERVICE_REQUEST_ITEM_DOCS (Col1, Col2, Col3)
    OUTPUT inserted.DOCUMENT_ID INTO @TID(DOCUMENT_ID)
    VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')

SELECT @DOCUMENT_ID = DOCUMENT_ID FROM @TID
```